# XPath Selecting all elements which doesn't have a particular element in the ancestor list

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<Root>
  <SomeElement>
    ...
    <Wanted>.....</Wanted>
    <UnWanted>
      <Wanted>.....</Wanted>
    </UnWanted>
    <Wanted>.....</Wanted>
    ...
  </SomeElement>
</Root>
```

I want to select the "`Wanted`" Elements which are inside "`SomeElement`" at ANY level but not childs of "`UnWanted`" Element.

With the XPath `/Root/SomeElement//Wanted` I'm not able to exclude the childs of `UnWanted`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
/Root/SomeElement//Wanted[not(ancestor::UnWanted)]
```

This would exclude all `Wanted` elements that are a child, grandchild, etc. (at any level) of an `UnWanted` element.  If you only want to exclude `Wanted` elements that are a *direct child* of `UnWanted` (but still include those that are grandchildren, etc.) then change `ancestor::` to `parent::`

```
/Root/SomeElement//Wanted[not(parent::UnWanted)]
```